# How do I get the Id of a user given the email address in ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

I have user information in my database. I wish to get the ID of a user given the email address. To get this in sql you would write the following query code:

```
SELECT Id FROM TableName WHERE email_address = "xyz@somename.com";
```

How do I write this using ASP.NET MVC Entity-Framework?

Comment: I would start by running through some very basic Entity Framework tutorials as this is essentially basic functionality.

Comment: you can use entity framework database first

Comment: @GustiArya I'm using code-first approach

Comment: @DavidG: Basics is covered already. I need to achieve the above without stress  so threw it open to the good people in the community.

Comment: If you had the basics covered, you wouldn't need to ask this question. Sorry, not trying to be patronising, but the question is really trivial.

Comment: @DavidG: Ok...would you at least give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends entirely on your public API, which we have no visibility into. Generally speaking, it would look something like:

```
var userId = db.Users
    .Where(m => m.email_address == "xyz@somename.com")
    .Select(m => m.Id)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

I suggest you take some time with the tutorials at https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/models-data, to get your bearings.